# Json Pagination not working from PageImpl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data

I have this controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
    public ResponseEntity<?> a(Pageable pageable) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(  );
        File file = new File( "samplejson.json" );
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree( file );
        List<JsonNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        if ( !jsonNode.isArray() )
            nodes.add( jsonNode );
        else 
            for ( JsonNode node : jsonNode )
                nodes.add( node );
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>( new PageImpl( nodes, pageable, nodes.size() ), HttpStatus.OK );
    }
```

and when i postman it, it gives me this response:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "Dode",
            "email": "dcardall0@zimbio.com",
            "gender": "Female",
            "timestamp": "11/12/1981"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Andrus",
            "email": "amcgeever1@jigsy.com",
            "gender": "Male",
            "timestamp": "10/25/1988"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Allyn",
            "email": "afakes2@samsung.com",
            "gender": "Male",
            "timestamp": "9/3/1997"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Merell",
            "email": "mmoreton3@census.gov",
            "gender": "Male",
            "timestamp": "3/7/2009"
        }
    ],
    "last": true,
    "totalElements": 10,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
        "sort": [
    {
        "direction": "DESC",
        "property": "id",
        "ignoreCase": false,
        "nullHandling": "NATIVE",
        "descending": true,
        "ascending": false
    }
],
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 10 }
```

in the URI i have this

```
http://localhost:8080/api?sort=id, desc
```

However the pagination isn't working. As you can see, the sort direction in the response says "DESC". So it's supposed to be in descending order, right? But it's not working. I think because it's inside an object content which was created by pagination. But i don't know how to access what's inside content.

Answer (score 0):

in order to apply PageRequest options like sort etc. you need to use PagingAndSortingRepository  (see [Spring Paging documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html))

So the sorting and getting the page is executed inside repository logic. See org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage

You can also go through this tutorial: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/

Comment: I'm aware of the PagingAndSortingRepository. However, I'm getting my data from a jsonfile. Is it still applicable? What I know with using Repositories is that I need to configure an sql database or h2 in the application.properties. But this is from a jsonfile. Is it possible to import a json file in application.properties as a database?

Comment: in order to make paging and sorting work with json file you need to implement the logic yourself. You can refer to existing PagingAndSortingRepository implementations as an example